# Do until last active line VBA

Tags: excel, vba

maybe someone can help me on this one.

I want to insert a new column and aplly the following code until the last line with data:

```
  =IF(RC[-1]="""","""",RC[-1]-INT(RC[-1]))
```

So I've tried this:

```
'Insert New Column
   Columns("M:M").Select
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

'Do until last line with data
  Dim contl As Variant
    contl = 1

  Do While Cells(contl, 12) <> ""
    contl = contl + 1
Loop

Range("M2:M" & contl).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="""","""",RC[-1] INT(RC[-1]))"
```

But it doesn't apply until the last active line, just the first one..
Any ideas why?
Thanks!

Comment: You don't have anything happening in your `Do` loop - what's it's purpose?  I think all you need to do is put your last line before the `Loop`.  (Edit: You just edited the post, but I don't know what you edited, or what your question was really.)

Comment: Yes, it make sense to put the last line inside the Loop.. But for some reason it worked in here this way.
Right, about the edit, I didn't change the code after posting because it started working, so all I changed it was the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with the last answer. First, in this loop,

```
Dim contl As Long
contl = 1
Do While Cells(contl, 12) <> ""
    contl = contl + 1
Loop
Debug.Print contl
```

That will end up with contl being one number higher than you want it since it has to find a blank cell before leaving the loop. This could be fixed with this modification.

```
Do While Cells(contl + 1, 12) <> ""
```

The second issue is simply using a loop at all. You can come from the bottom and look up to the last populated cell in column L.

```
contl = Range("L2:L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("M2:M" & contl).FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-1]=TEXT(,), TEXT(,), RC[-1] INT(RC[-1]))"
```

This is the same as going to the very bottom of column L (e.g. L1048576) and tapping [ctrl]+[↑]. You are filling in all of the formulas at once and that saves time and effort but the loop to find the last populated cell is ruining the benefits.

Note that I've used `TEXT(,)` in place of `""""`. They are the same thing (e.g. an empty string) and might be a little less confusing.

Comment: These are some really good improvements, thank you!
The way I had posted started to work (don't really know why..), but the way you wrote is way is better, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue, hope it can help someone. Cheers!

```
 Sub Macro1()
'Insert New Column
    Columns("M:M").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

 'Do until last line with data
   Dim contl As Variant
     contl = 1

   Do While Cells(contl, 12) <> "" 'The number here is the number of the column (A=1, B=2...)
     contl = contl + 1
 Loop

 Range("M2:M" & contl).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="""","""",RC[-1] INT(RC[-1]))" 'Change the range of the column if necessary
```

Comment: The appropriate way to handle this is to post the corrected code as an answer and leave the question unchanged.  This way future people can see the problem and then the eventual fix.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't really know how to post like this. 
Jeeped answer made a big improvement, so I guess I'll delete this one and mark that as the final answer, thanks for pointing it out!